# CakePHP 1.3 Elements

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How would i go about turning this code into an element to reuse across my web application?

```
<div class="row">

<?php foreach ($mobiles as $mobile): ?>
    <ul class="product-listing unstyled">
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->webroot . 'mobiles/view/'.$mobile['Mobile']['id']; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; echo 'files/files'.$mobile['Mobile']['filename']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $mobile['Mobile']['productname']; ?>" />
            <div class="pricing pull-right">&euro;<?php echo $mobile['Mobile']['price']; ?> </div>
            <h3><?php echo $mobile['Mobile']['productname']; ?></h3>
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: http://php.net/include

Comment: i'd like to reuse this code on multiple views the only thing i'm unsure about is how i can dynamically change the values.. meaning $mobiles becomes $tablets and the the model changes as well from Mobile to Tablet

Answer (score 1):

### Cut and paste

An element is just a bit of view code - create an element:

```
// /views/elements/foo.ctp
<div class="row">

<?php foreach ($mobiles as $mobile): ?>
...
```

And simply call it in your view files (or layouts - or other elements):

```
// /widgets/index.ctp

<?php echo $this->element('foo'); ?>
```

### How to pass variables to an element

As described [in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element), it's possible to pass variables to an element:

```
<?php echo
$this->element('helpbox',
    array("helptext" => "Oh, this text is very helpful."));
?>
```

> Inside the element file, all the passed variables are available as members of the parameter array (in the same way that set() in the controller works with view files). In the above example, the /app/views/elements/helpbox.ctp file can use the $helptext variable.

```
// /views/elements/helpbox.ctp
<?php
echo $helptext; //outputs "Oh, this text is very helpful."
?>
```

### If it's variable - make it a variable

> the model changes as well from Mobile to Tablet

The example code in the question has the model name as a fixed string:

```
<h3><?php echo $mobile['Mobile']['productname']; ?></h3>
```

Just make it a variable:

```
<h3><?php echo $mobile[$modelName]['productname']; ?></h3>
```

And define it when calling the element.

Comment: One note: if you set a variable using $this->set() in any part of the controller/action code that ran while rendering the main layout or view (the view that calls the individual elements), those variables will be available already to the element. IE if you go to /controller/action and the AppController::beforeFilter() does `$this->set('var1', $somevar);`, and the 'action' view calls `$this->element('someelement');`, the `$var1` will be available in the 'someelement' element